# ReutersSource in R

Tags: r, tm, reuters

```
library(tm)  
reut21578 <- system.file("texts", "crude", package = "tm")  
reuters <- Corpus(DirSource(reut21578), 
                  readerControl = list(reader = readReut21578XML))  
file <- "reut-0001.xml"   
reuters <- Corpus(ReutersSource(file), readerControl = list(reader = readReut21578XML))
```

I am using tm package for accessing reuters data but IN ReutersSource i am getting error

> Error in inherits(x, "Source") : could not find function "ReutersSource"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the developers have removed `ReutersSource()` from the source code of the tm package.

If you want to read in a single specific file you can pass a filter expression to the `DirSource()` function, like this:

```
reuters <- Corpus(DirSource(reut21578, pattern = "00001.xml"), 
                   readerControl = list(reader = readReut21578XMLasPlain))

   cat(content(reuters[[1]]))
```

Result:

> Diamond Shamrock Corp said that effective today it had cut its
>   contract prices for crude oil by
>   1.50 dlrs a barrel.
>       The reduction brings its posted price for West Texas Intermediate to 16.00 dlrs a barrel, the copany said.
>       "The price reduction today was made in the light of falling oil product prices and a weak crude oil market," a company spokeswoman
>   said.
>       Diamond is the latest in a line of U.S. oil companies that have cut its contract, or posted, prices over the last two days citing weak
>   oil markets.  Reuter